# rails tutorial account activation: how do i whitelabel my rails app on sendgrid deployed with heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid, white-labelling

I have tried many ways to whitelabel my app on sendgrid. unfortunately the Rails tutorial does not go into any detail on how to do this.

in order to use sendgrid you must validate your account. the final step is whitelisting. I must admit that i have absolutely no idea how to do this step or what it means. there are various fields that i must fill in.

so far i have the following for my app, which is at https://still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com/

```
subdomain: still-beyond-10331.herokuapp 
domain: .com
```

then there were 3 lines, each with 2 fields which were automatically prefilled with data (HOST and DATA) so i clicked on validate. these fields were the following

```
Type: CNAME, HOST: still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com, DATA: u6460287.wl038.sendgrid.net

Type: CNAME, HOST: s1._domainkey.com, DATA: s1.domainkey.u6460287.wl038.sendgrid.net

Type: CNAME HOST: s2._domainkey.com, DATA: s2.domainkey.u6460287.wl038.sendgrid.net
```

when i clicked on "validate" i got the following error:

```
Error validating whitelabel:
• Expected CNAME for "still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com" to match "u6460287.wl038.sendgrid.net".
• Expected CNAME for "s1._domainkey.com" to match "s1.domainkey.u6460287.wl038.sendgrid.net".
• Expected CNAME for "s2._domainkey.com" to match "s2.domainkey.u6460287.wl038.sendgrid.net".

DNS providers may take up to 48 hours to make your changes public. If your records are correct in your DNS host, you may have to revalidate in a few hours in order to begin utilizing your domain.
```

The problem i have is that i have read the documentation but dont understand it. it assumes a certain knowledge of the terms used. this stage has me completely lost. what are the correct imputs for the fields shown above?

Comment: i didnt get the question, what doesnt work ? sending email or validating smth from email ?

Comment: @7urkm3n. the whitelabelling process does not work. I havent even got to the point of sending emails yet becasue i can not validate the whitelabel process to use the sendgrid account.  I am not sure if the fields that are shown above HOST and DATA, contain the correct information. I am pretty sure that they don't because of the error. What should these fields contain? there is very little information available about this on their site. how can i obtain the correct information to fill in these fields from my app at heroku?